# Finish fragment with it's host activity as a whole

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, lifecycle

#### When I have to finish an activity with only one fragment in it, I noticed that the fragment disapears ealier before the blank activity(the container activity) finish itself.

How you guys handle this situation?

### SingleFragmentActivity.java:

```
    public class SingleFragmentActivity extends BaseSecondaryActivity{

        public static final java.lang.String FRAGMENT_CLASS_NAME = "fragment_class_name";
        public static final java.lang.String FRAGMENT_TITLE = "fragment_title";
        private String title;
        private ActionBarFragment fragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            String fragmentName = bundle.getString(FRAGMENT_CLASS_NAME);
            if(bundle.getInt(FRAGMENT_TITLE) == 0){
                title = "";
            }else {
                title = getString(bundle.getInt(FRAGMENT_TITLE));
            }
            try {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Class<ActionBarFragment> fragmentClass  = (Class<ActionBarFragment>) Class.forName(fragmentName);
                fragment = fragmentClass.newInstance();
                bundle.remove(FRAGMENT_TITLE);
                bundle.remove(FRAGMENT_CLASS_NAME);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected int provideContentViewId() {
            return R.layout.activity_with_fragment;
        }

        protected String getActionBarTitleString() {
            return title;
        }
    }
```

### activity_with_fragment.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/action_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "When I have to finish an activity"?  Are you explicitly calling finish()?

Comment: yes, I mean calll finish(), the activity screen become blank after the remove the fragment, and then the activity finishes itself

Comment: first there is no need for `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` second you do not check if  `savedInstanceState` is not null then you shouldn't create fragment again ... also you didn't provide information about where and how are you calling `finish`

Comment: savedInstanceState is not used here, and finish is called here:    Override
  ` public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    } `in BaseSecondaryActivity @Selvin

Comment: @JaceHo did you ever find a solution?